# Can I use two different styles for checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I am using this css styling for checkboxes to be used on smartphones, so they would appear larger than usuall.

```
    input[type="checkbox"] 
    {
    display:none;
    }
input[type="checkbox"] + label span 
    {
    display:inline-block;
    width:26px;
    height:26px;
    margin:0px 0px 0 5px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url(images/checkbox1.png) left top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span 
    {
    background:url(images/checkbox2.png) left top no-repeat;
    }
```

And the HTML

```
<input type="Checkbox" id="c_1">
<label for="c_1"><span></span></label>
```

And it affects all checkboxes on my site. But I need to use "ordinary" chekboxes in same pages.
How would I do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What happened to all the answers and notations? I only edited my question for some spelling and now they´re gone!

Comment: You need to add different id's to your checkboxes, or different classes to a checkbox, or checkbox group

Answer (score 1):

You have to differ "ordinary" from the other checkboxes which is usally done by a css class.
If ordinary means "unstyled", then just add a style to your custom checkboxes and adjust your css styling rules, to just affect inputs typed as checkboxes with your defined class.

see: http://jsfiddle.net/75p7cbgm/

```
input.cl[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I used your code and it makes the checkbox to accupy more place not getting bigger. I use FireFox in windows 7

Comment: i just used width and height for demonstration, just use your styling extended by a classname